# Cannot connect to local or remote servers, connection reset by peer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I made a bukkit server on my computer running OS X. No problems there. I opened up my client (on the same computer), open multiplayer, the direct connect and typed in "127.0.0.1:25565". It appeared to accept that. It showed "logging in" (I am using a premium account). Then it would fail and give me the error "End of Stream". The server console showed that my disconnect was a "genericDisconnect". Any idea why this isn't working?

Note: My internet is ridicoulsly slow. I don't live in the U.S. or an European country. Upgrading internet isn't an option. I however didn't think that the internet would matter if it was on the same computer as the client.

EDIT: I made a vanilla server, setting up server worked fine. When I tried to connect using 127.0.0.1:25565 I got this error:

`2013-11-11 13:54:29 [CLIENT] [INFO] Connecting to 127.0.0.1, 25565
2013-11-11 13:54:33 [CLIENT] [INFO] [CHAT] DonyorM joined the game.
2013-11-11 13:54:33 [CLIENT] [SEVERE] Reached end of stream for /127.0.0.1`

The error shown on the client was `Internal Exception: java.io.IOException Connection reset by peer`
I got the same error when connecting to a powerful public server in europe. I still get the end of stream error when using the bukkit server (which is 1.6.4, the vanilla server is 1.7.2).

When trying to connect using my external ip address and the port, I got a `Connection Refused` error. I think that's the wrong ip address.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try connecting through your actual IP address?

Comment: Have you joined other multiplayer servers successfully? Have you tried hosting a regular MC server?

Comment: First, run a vanilla server and see if you have the same problem. If you can connect to a vanilla server then it's a bukkit configuration problem; if you can't, then there is something external to the server wrong.

Comment: @Studoku I think I tried that, and I couldn't  connect at all. I should type in <myexternalipadress>:25565 right?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Did the vanilla server didn't work, see post above.

Comment: @kotekzot I can't connect to other servers. I normally get the same error.

Comment: Uh, why would the client say it can't ping `sssminecraft.com` when you're trying to connect to your own server? Are you sure you've pasted the correct error line?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Err, yeah I copy and pasted wrong line.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually specifying the client version in the launcher. Start the launcher, click Edit Profile, then under "Use version" specify the version compatible with your CraftBukkit server.

I received the same error connecting to both the stable (1.6.4) and beta (1.7.9) versions of CraftBukkit, but I could connect to a vanilla server (1.6.4) on the same remote machine without issue. The clue that tipped me off was connecting to the beta server returned an error that said "outdated server, I'm on 1.7.9!" My client is currently 1.8. I assumed the latest client was compatible with older servers, and for the vanilla server that seems to be the case, but for CraftBukkit you may need to manually specify the version.

Comment: I did this a while ago, but I made sure it was the right version. CraftBukkit was updated to the lastest version at the time. Right now, I've stopped bothering with a server and moved on to other things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any firewalls, try disabling those. Also, in your server.properties, try changing `online-mode` to false. This will disable authentication of Minecraft accounts so cracked players will be able to get onto your server. If you are just hosting it at home for your own pleasure, you should be OK.

Comment: Tried all of those things. Doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it is the ping :(

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you are hosting it on the same computer. You can disable your internet and still connect to a local server.

Comment: What ip do I use? I used 127.0.0.1:25565 and it still gave me an end of stream error.

Comment: Try simply using localhost.

Comment: Having problems getting the jar file to work. Not server related. Have to wait for it to download the 1.6.4 jar. Can't try till it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when connecting to a local server on the same machine you dont use the external ip. You use the internal one, this is the ip that the router gives you, usually 192.168.1.xxxx. To find this check the status of your internet connection. It should be listed there. If your still lost i will get on my mac and give you specific steps

Comment: I think you are missing at least a couple of points here: 1) He cannot connect to *any* server, not just his own. 2) He is already using LAN IPs when testing against his local servers.

Comment: Yeah, Zero3 pretty much said it. Also, consider adding punctuation and such to your posts. IT's a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can connect to neither local nor remote servers, this seems to be a client problem. "Connection reset by peer" basically mean that the server hung up and tossed you out (but that you managed to connect in the first place!).

This common practice if the client does not act as expected, either because of corruption or (more likely) an outdated/buggy client installation. I would suggest that you reinstall your Minecraft client and ensure that you test it against the vanilla servers before applying any kind of third party patches/mods (which is quite common in the world of Minecraft IIRC).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test it on another computer in this house, so I can really test it then.

Answer (score -3):

Type in `localhost:25565` when you want to play alone. Type localhost when you want friends to play with you.

Comment: Does it make a difference? I don't think it does.